# Discord.py - Execute a function in a function while the function is still running

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to run a timer function in a function that edit an embed while leaving the initial function running, but I can't find how to do that... Here's my code:

```py
@bot.command(aliases = ['pc'])
async def pour_combien(ctx, lim, reverse, *gage):

    async def timer(time, msg_to_edit):
        while time >= 0:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"• {time} secondes restantes...\n\n\u270B Pour accepter     \u274c Pour annuler (seulement pour le créateur)")
            time -= 1
            await msg_to_edit.edit(embed=embed)

    time = 30.0
    embed = discord.Embed([.......])
    embed.set_footer(text=f"• {time} secondes restantes...\n\n\u270B Pour accepter     \u274c Pour annuler (seulement pour le créateur)")
    demande = await ctx.send(embed= embed)
    await demande.add_reaction("\u270B")
    await demande.add_reaction("\u274c")

    await timer(time, demande)

    while True: 
        try:
            reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=time, check=lambda reaction, user: reaction.emoji in [u'\u270B',u'\u274c']) 
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return
        else:
            if reaction.emoji == u'\u270B':
                if user != ctx.author:
                    player2 = user
                    break
            else:
                if user == ctx.author:
                    return
```

So I would like to run `await timer(time, demande)` and `While True: [...]` at the same time, I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: You are looking for multithreading, or `threads`. This has nothing to do with discord.py. Just google for a threads example and you should be able to figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use threading to run them at the same time.

```
import threading

threading.Thread(target=timer, args=[time, msg_to_edit]).start()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But when I use threading it calls an error `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'pour_combien.<locals>.timer' was never awaited` but it's impossible to await threading?...

Comment: Yes, it's possible. `bot.loop.create_task(timer(time, msg_to_edit))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use threading, but why do that in an asynchronous environment. We can simply use asyncio for that.

```py
async def wait_for_reaction_add():
    #while loop here

# inside command
await asyncio.gather(timer(time, demande), wait_for_reaction_add()
```

asyncio.gather runs both the coroutines concurrently

### References:

- [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)
- [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently)